# phrase meaning: "crash-bang wallop"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Have you ever heard of crash-bang wallop? What does it mean? Found this in my homework text and looks like it's not a translatable one... I've tried finding it but that's just a hopeless try...

Comment: Have you tried [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22crash-bang+wallop%22&client=safari&hl=en&prmd=imsvn&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCgqPP7pnlAhWIv54KHQt6ClwQ_AUIEigG&biw=320&bih=372)?

Comment: yes. probably this is going to be known tomorrow as i see my teacher

Answer (score 1):

'Crash-bang-wallop' is a slightly old-fashioned, mainly British dramatic [interjection](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interjection). An interjection is one or more words inserted between other words to convey drama or emphasis. For example, 'bang!' used here:

> The car crashed into a tree, then - bang! - it exploded.

In a similar way, I can say:

> I was sitting watching the TV, when - crash-bang-wallop! - a truck
>   came through the wall of my house

Comment: in my text this phrase was used as "i was always the crash-bang wallop". Does it make any sense then???

Comment: It doesn't make much sense.  It probably means "I was always the one who made lots of noise" or "the one who caused the accident" or perhaps "the one who was laughed at" (at the end of a joke, the drums play "crash bang wallop" to mark the punchline) or something similar. More context is needed.